# How to call parent constructor in PHP OOP?

Tags: php, class, oop, constructor

I am building a web and cli based application. Since the cli contains functions that are also required for the web, I want to nest both together.

```
<?php
class API {

    protected $Settings;
    protected $Database;
    protected $FTP;
    protected $LDAP;
    protected $Auth;
    protected $Alerts;

    public function __contruct(){
        date_default_timezone_set($site['timezone']);
        if($Settings['debug']){ error_reporting(-1); } else { error_reporting(0); }
        $this->Settings = $Settings;
        $this->Alerts = array();
        $this->Database = new DB($Settings['sql']['host'], $Settings['sql']['username'], $Settings['sql']['password'], $Settings['sql']['database']);
        $this->FTP = new FTP($Settings['ftp']['username'],$Settings['ftp']['password'],$Settings['ftp']['host']);
        $this->LDAP = new LDAP($Settings['ldap']['username'],$Settings['ldap']['password'],$Settings['ldap']['host'],$Settings['ldap']['port'],$Settings['ldap']['domain'],$Settings['ldap']['base'],$Settings['ldap']['branches']);
        $this->Auth = new Auth();
    }
}

class Application extends API {

    protected $Router;
    protected $URL;
    protected $fullURL;

    public function __construct($Settings){
        $this->Router = new \Bramus\Router\Router();
        $this->URL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
        $this->fullURL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    }
}
```

But it seems when I create the application with `$App = new Application($Settings);`, only the Application constructor is running. 
But I am trying to get all the properties of the API Class in the Application class. Which is what I though would happen if I was using inheritance.

Can someone help me achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `Application` class' constructor you have to explicitly call the parent constructor:

```php
public function __construct($Settings){
    $this->Router = new \Bramus\Router\Router();
    $this->URL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/';
    $this->fullURL = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http")."://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    parent::__construct(); // <- Add this
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Now if I continue nesting, as long as my __construc function calls it's parent, I should be able to nest as much as I want correct?

Comment: Yes, but you have to care about your parent constructor's parameters. If, for example, you want to add a class `CliApplication` that extends `Application`, in `CliApplication` constructor you have to use: `parent::__construct($Settings);`